# How to associate tables via id

Tags: database, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I associate two tables in Sequelize? I tried `belongsTo`, but this doesn't work. Example:

First table:

```
users = sequelize.define('users', {
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
},
name: Sequelize.TEXT,
type: Sequelize.INTEGER
```

Second table:

```
profiles = sequelize.define('profiles', {
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
},
place: Sequelize.TEXT,
phone: Sequelize.INTEGER
```

Association:

```
profiles.belongsTo(users, {foreignKey: 'id'});
```

Request:

```
users.findOne({
    where: {name: 'John'}, 
    include: [{model: db.tables.profiles}]
}).then(function(user_data) {
    console.log(user_data);
})
```

Returned `[Error: profiles is not associated to users!]`

I need to return the matched line of "users" and the line with the same id from the table 'profiles'. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the association for both tables.  From your schema I can't tell what the join condition is.  If your profiles table also has a column `user_id` such that `profiles.user_id = users.id`, then you could say the following:

```
users.hasMany(profiles, {
  foreignKey: 'id'
});

profiles.belongsTo(users, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});
```